# /dev/loop0 is full

Tags: partitioning, mount

I have a problem that `/dev/loop0` is 100% , how can I fix this ?
Anyone know what application using this path `/snap/core/1337`?

And the output of `df -h` command

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           799M  9.7M  789M   2% /run
/dev/sda1       909G  336G  528G  39% /
tmpfs           3.9G   62M  3.9G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       76M   76M     0 100% /snap/core/1337
cgmfs           100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs           799M  104K  798M   1% /run/user/1000
```

ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my /dev/loop0 showing full?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/211693/why-is-my-dev-loop0-showing-full)

Comment: What's the output of `losetup /dev/loop0`?