# File system is getting full quickly. Most of the directories all full

Tags: filesystem, cleanup

I was trying to clean my ubuntu system and saw that most of the system directories look 100% full. Is this normal? How can I clean these (if unnecessary) files?

[this how file system looks in the system monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHYMs.png)

Comment: Related: [system mounts /dev/loop0 on /snap/core/3604 and it's 100% full, where is it coming from?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990013/system-mounts-dev-loop0-on-snap-core-3604-and-its-100-full-where-is-it-comi)

Answer (score 1):

This is normal. The /dev/loopx filesystem objects are for snaps - one for each snap application installed. This is what my system looks like (running command `df -hl`)

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs           766M  3.4M  763M   1% /run
/dev/dm-0       225G   38G  176G  18% /
tmpfs           3.8G  772M  3.0G  21% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       59M   59M     0 100% /snap/powershell-preview/82
/dev/loop1       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1754
/dev/loop2       66M   66M     0 100% /snap/powershell-preview/87
/dev/loop3       28M   28M     0 100% /snap/snapd/7264
/dev/nvme0n1p1  300M  8.1M  292M   3% /boot/efi
tmpfs           766M   28K  766M   1% /run/user/1000
```